# changing to a specific activity when a listview item is clicked

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a list view with 3 items , I want to move to a new activity depending on the item being clicked , that is each item when clicked should move to a different activity . I have tried the solution which were given to similar problems , but  I still didn't figure out how to make it go to another activity

```
package com.example.wizer;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Options extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    WifiManager wifi;
    BroadcastReceiver receiver;
    IntentFilter filter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_options);
        wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        filter = new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);


        registerReceiver(rcver, filter);

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.l1);

        ArrayList < String > List = new ArrayList < String > ();
        List.add("List available networks .");
        List.add("List APs .");
        List.add("List Networks according to thier signal strength .");

        ArrayAdapter < String > adp = new ArrayAdapter < String > (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, List);
        list.setAdapter(adp);

        wifi.startScan();
    }

    // On create
    final BroadcastReceiver rcver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        };

    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_options, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView <? > arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (arg3 == 0) {
            Intent NL = new Intent(Options.this, Networks.class);
            startActivity(NL);

        } else if (arg3 == 1) {

            Intent NL = new Intent(Options.this, AP.class);
            startActivity(NL);



        } else if (arg3 == 2) {
            Intent NL = new Intent(Options.this, Signal.class);
            startActivity(NL);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer :
I had to add this after the list declaration

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
```

This line will give you the row number and a reference to the view for that particular cell. In your View, you can add a property with the class so you can later open that activity. This will require a custom view class and a custom adapter to fill it.

Alternatively, if your list will be simple, you can create an Array of classes that match the ordering of the rows.

```
Class[] classes = new Class[2];
        classes[0] = Integer.class;
        classes[1] = View.class;
```

Then you can just use the row number to get the correct class reference.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm totally new can you explain further? where should I add the class ? what parameter is the row number ? If my list contains 3 item the items rows' are 0,1,2??

Comment: You are passed in the row id in the onItemClick listener. Use that as the array index example classes[row]. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html . Pragnani's answer is also good.

Comment: I have three item so do I have to make class[3] ?? why you wrote classes[0] = Integer.class;
        classes[1] = View.class; and what should I do in case of my 3 items?

Comment: Sorry, it was just an example of filling in the class array with different class objects. In your case, you will want to size the array and assign as meets your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

your code should be like this

```
public class Options extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {


    Wizer wizer;
    BroadcastReceiver receiver;
    IntentFilter filter;
    HashMap<String,Class> map=new HashMap<String,Class>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_options);
        wizer.Wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        filter=new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);

        registerReceiver(rcver,filter );



        map.put("List available networks .",Networks.class);
        map.put("List APs .", AP.class);     // your second class name
        map.put("List Networks according to thier signal strength .",Signal.class); // third class name 
  }
     final BroadcastReceiver rcver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

         @Override
         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

         };

};
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_options, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Class c= map.get(arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString());
        Intent NL =new Intent(Options.this,c);
        startActivity(NL);
    }
}
```

---

Try this

Take a HashMap

```
HashMap<String,Class> map=new HashMap(String,Class);


map.put("List available networks .",Networks.class);
map.put("List APs .", Second.class);     // your second class name
map.put("List Networks according to thier signal strength .",Third.class); // third class name
```

And then in onItemClick

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

    Class c= map.get(arg0.getItemAtPosition().toString());
    Intent NL =new Intent(Options.this,c);
    startActivity(NL);
}
```

**Note**:When you have less items don't use ListView, use LinearLayout with scrollview instead

Comment: class and string are generic types...Press ctrl+shift+o and declare HashMap as field and assign values in onCreate

Comment: @Alaa For asking about the **Note** ?

Comment: yes i removed the list view , now what should I do in the xml do I have to add both linear layout and scroll view?

Comment: @Alaa In your xml get the parent Id and new Dynamic textViews and Add each to LinearLayout and then to Scrollview. finally add Scrollview to parent reference...Do this things later, for now continue with Listview

Comment: I didn't get that !I should use the list view on the xml file or change the whole code to use the listview????

Comment: @Alaa That why I told you to continue with your origianl code using ListView as you are not able to understand(I mean as you are newbie).